# How to Create a PUT request in Python for the following JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON body like this:

```
'\n{\n"users" : \n[\n\n{\n"dn" : null,\n"dns_domain" : null,\n"domain" : "UNIX_USERS",\n"email" : null,\n"enabled" : true,\n"expired" : false,\n"expiry" : null,\n"gecos" : "InsightIQ User",\n"generated_gid" : false,\n"generated_uid" : false,\n"generated_upn" : true,\n"gid" : \n{\n"id" : "GID:15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "group"\n},\n"home_directory" : "/ifs/home/insightiq",\n"id" : "insightiq",\n"locked" : false,\n"max_password_age" : null,\n"member_of" : null,\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"object_history" : [],\n"on_disk_group_identity" : \n{\n"id" : "GID:15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "group"\n},\n"on_disk_user_identity" : \n{\n"id" : "UID:15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "user"\n},\n"password_expired" : false,\n"password_expires" : true,\n"password_expiry" : null,\n"password_last_set" : null,\n"primary_group_sid" : \n{\n"id" : "SID:S-1-22-2-15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "group"\n},\n"prompt_password_change" : false,\n"provider" : "lsa-file-provider:System",\n"sam_account_name" : "insightiq",\n"shell" : "/sbin/nologin",\n"sid" : \n{\n"id" : "SID:S-1-22-1-15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "user"\n},\n"type" : "user",\n"uid" : \n{\n"id" : "UID:15",\n"name" : "insightiq",\n"type" : "user"\n},\n"upn" : "insightiq@UNIX_USERS",\n"user_can_change_password" : false\n}\n]\n}\n')
```

Now I want to create a PUT request in python so as to change the value of "enabled" to false.
This is what I have, but I keep getting a 400 bad request.

```
def revert_insightIQ_user_account(self):
    ''' Revert insightIQ_user_account'''

    print "Reverting insightIQ user to default... "
    req_url = "/platform/1/auth/users/insightiq"
    default = {}
    default['users'] = []
    default['users'].append({})
    default["users"][0]["enabled"] = False
    self.http_papi.httpPut(self.base_url, self.port, self.username, self.password, req_url, req_body=default)
    print "Settings reverted successfully.."
```

I think I am creating the JSON body format wrongly, because the URL and all is correct (i have double checked that) but I can't figure out what would be the correct one and have reached a dead end. Can someone please help?

edit:
http_papi is a library created which has all the API transactions like GET PUT defined, so whenever I use an API request I call it from that library (it has been imported)

The JSON string source is the URI mentioned : /platform/1/auth/users/insightiq (this along with the cluster IP I am using for my testing)

The JSON string posted is what I get back when I do a raw CURL put request to enable the user. I have to create a same JSON format in my python code and pass enabled = false there.

Comment: you should take a look at requests, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: what is `http_papi`? And what is the source of the JSON string? And how is the JSON string related to anything in your code - it doesn't seem to be used anywhere. And what is the point of `a` and `b` which you're also not using anywhere?

Comment: http_papi is a library created which has all the API transactions like GET PUT defined, so whenever I use an API request I call it from that library (it has been imported)
The JSON string source is the URI mentioned : /platform/1/auth/users/insightiq (this along with the cluster IP I am using for my testing)
The JSON string posted is what I get back when I do a raw CURL put request to enable the user.
I have to create a same JSON format in my python code and pass enabled = false there.
I am creating a and b as empty list/dict because have to match the format of the JSON we get to pass PUT

Comment: just realised I posted a piece of dead code. removed the a and b lines and posted what I am using now. can you please check @Daniel?

Answer (score 0):

this worked by just changing the list object "enabled" didn't have to create the DS from scratch.

def revert_insightIQ_user_account(self):
        ''' Revert insightIQ_user_account'''

```
    print
    print "Reverting insightIQ user to default... "
    default = {}
    req_url = "/platform/1/auth/users/insightiq"
    default['enabled'] = False
    self.http_papi.httpPut(self.base_url, self.port, self.username, self.password, req_url, req_body=default)
    print "Settings reverted successfully..
```